# Как правильно сделать топ публикаций с критериями отбора?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть список публикаций, книги... У каждой такой книги есть 2 значения, **view = просмотры** и **like = нравится**.
Пример моего кода выводит записи не так как правильно, не знаю точно как Вы делали подобные схемы вывода, могли бы Вы подсказать, как правильно вообще делать подобный топ записей?

---

**Вот собственно сам запрос вывода из базы:**

```
$sql_top_view = mysql_query("
SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM `book` 
WHERE `view`>='$book[view]' AND `like`>='$book[like]' 
ORDER BY `view` , `like` 
LIMIT 1000"); 
$top_view = mysql_fetch_row($sql_top_view);
$top = $top_view[0];

    if($top >= 1000){
        $top_number_view = '1000+';
    }else{
        $top_number_view = $top;
    }

echo $top_number_view;
```

**Данный код выводит данные примерно так:**

```
1 место: 7 like , 289 view.
1 место: 9 like , 268 view.
1 место: 17 like , 233 view.
4 место: 7 like , 78 view.
и.т.д.
```

**А надо:**

```
1 место: 7 like , 289 view.
2 место: 9 like , 268 view.
3 место: 17 like , 233 view.
4 место: 7 like , 78 view.
и.т.д.
```

---

Но еще интересовало, каким образом еще можно сделать значение like важнее чем view, к примеру 1 like = 20 view, и если попадется книга со значение 1 like а другая с 10 like, то на первое место ставить первую книгу?

Comment: У вас запрос очень странный. Есть count() но нет group by. по хорошему при таком раскладе он должен вернуть только одну запись. И сортировка по полям view и like после группировки (которую внес нам count()) вообще не имеет смысла потому как для группы значение отдельных колонок случайно. может там должен быть sum() или еще что нибудь такое

Comment: А если 1 like = 20 view то видимо общий рейтинг считать как `20*like+view`

Comment: @Mike Да выводит 1 запись, я просто показал по какой схеме он выводит, типа того что он добавляет несколько записей к 1 месту а потом резко на 4.

Comment: @Mike Что-то у меня не получается. Не сталкивался еще с таким выводом. Могли бы Вы на примере показать, как это сделать?

Comment: Ну так ваш запрос не соответствует выводу. Откуда например вообще берутся номера мест ? Наверное там где они выводятся надо завести переменную которая будет тупо увеличиваться на 1 на каждом цикле

Comment: @Mike Кажется я плохо объясняю( Этот вывод должен выводить на страницу место в топе, одно.  Я сделал подсчет места через count. Но это не правильно...

Comment: Как одно ... По хорошему весь вывод если он из одних и тех же таблиц должен делаться одним единственным запросом в БД, который возвращает много строк.

Comment: И надо заметить что вычислить место в топе одной записи невозможно, не посчитав его при этом для всех остальных...

Comment: @Mike Ну и как быть?

Comment: Написать в вопросе структуру таблиц, желательно с примером данных. К ней небольшое пояснение из какой таблицы что брать и что считается "самым топовым"